# Question about the double slit experiment 2

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I had wondered if anyone has ever tried doing the experiment with molecules, then I came across this webpage ( http://www.livescience.com/19268-quantum-double-slit-experiment-largest-molecules.html ). These researchers used 58 to 114 atom molecules, made up of carbon, hydrogen and nitrogen, and got the same results; getting an interference pattern. Now, I am wondering as to what limit can you go before this 'state of uncertainty' no longer works? If a water molecule had this affect, how big can you make the molecule until it no longer will produce the interference pattern and will it work once the molecule becomes an element or even a compond (is it the actual size or mass that's the factor?), I mean 114 mixed atom molecules seemed alot, what number of H2O molecules is needed before it no longer works and frankly, what number of H2O molecules is needed to classify it a compond? Because I can't help but think that 70% of my body mass is in this 'state of uncertainty'...lol

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please have a look at our [FAQ about question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: Your body isn't in a state of uncertainty and there is no way that it could be. In order to measure these effects you have to make sure that thermodynamic noise doesn't interfere with them. This requires ever lower temperatures the larger the object becomes and you wouldn't survive the ones needed to get you into a discernible quantum mechanical state. One can do experiments at the uncertainty level with very large metal objects at very low temperature, though, but that's a bit more involved than the double slit experiment.

Comment: Juffmann, T., Milic, A., Müllneritsch, M. et al. Real-time single-molecule imaging of quantum interference. Nature Nanotech 7, 297–300 (2012). https://doi.org/10.1038/nnano.2012.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Einstein proposed a quantum theory of light that settled the controversy over whether light was a wave or a particle, physicists wondered if wave/particle duality could apply to matter as well as to photons.  The [de Broglie hypothesis](http://physics.about.com/od/quantumphysics/a/dbhypothesis.htm) proposes that matter also possesses a wave/particle dual nature.  The simplest form of De Broglie's equation relates Planck's constant to a particle's momentum in order to derive its wavelength:

**Lambda = h / p**, where lambda is wavelength, h is Planck's constant, and p is momentum

He used momentum rather than energy because it wasn't clear whether kinetic energy should be included in the total, or alternatively if total relativistic energy should be used.

There is no reason why the de Broglie wavelength should not be applied to any matter, regardless of scale.  However the more massive the object, the greater its momentum, and the smaller its wavelength.  Macro scale objects would have very tiny wavelengths and, as Floris points out in his answer, there are great obstacles to measuring these wavelengths.

Your body is not in a meaningful state of uncertainty, because all the quanta of which it is made are entangled with each other and with the world you inhabit.  Their wave functions generally are in a state of [quantum decoherence](http://www.quora.com/What-is-quantum-decoherence), so your body is described by classical mechanics, which does not account for quantum uncertainty.

Comment: Hi, perhaps I wrote my question wrong;as I was only using the statement about the human body in an extreme point. These researchers used 114 atom molecules and got the same 'wave' like pattern...first, I don't know how many atom molecules it would take to classify it as an element or a compound...and what I'm asking is, if an H2O molecule can be shoot at the slits and produce the same results, how many H2O atom molecules can you add and fire at the slits, until the 'wave' like pattern no longer occurs? Is it the number of atom molecules that decides whether this phenomenom will occur or not?

Comment: After carefully reading both your answers, I actually do get what you are both saying. The greater the mass, it will require more energy for the atom molecules to hit the wavelength frequency that we would see, as if we were only firing one atom molecule at the 2 slits, at a time. So I guess that the number of atom molecules is only a small factor in the phenomenon, compared to it's speed; would that be correct to say? So would this phenomenon still occur, if you could somehow slow the speed of the molecule being fired (not it's rate, by the way)?

Comment: @DuhVillageIdiot: Researchers in Austria created a coherent beam of giant molecules made of 800 atoms each.  They passed these molecules through a series of slits. A detector showed an interference pattern. These 800-atom molecules, each with diameter 4 orders of magnitude greater than its wavelength, exhibited quantum uncertainty.  They did NOT split in two. They were superposed when they passed through the slits.  This link describes the experiment: https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b. I will answer your 2nd comment next.

Comment: @DuhVillageIdiot: The rate of firing doesn't matter. The double slit experiment has succeeded even when only 1 particle at a time passes through the slits, with no possibility of individual particles interfering with each other. Superposition happens with each individual particle. In effect, each particle acts as a wave in quantum superposition while it's traveling, passes through both slits at once, interferes, and exhibits its particle nature only when it hits the detector. While traveling, it's a wave. The evidence of superposition is the interference pattern that appears on the detector.

Comment: Thank You for the link, Ernie; that was quite informative. As for my second question; I knew that the rate of fire was irrelevent, I was wondering if superpostion still occurs, if you can somehow slow the actual speed of the molecules? I thought I read somewhere, of a way to slow down the actual speed of a particle.

Comment: @DuhVillageIdiot: It's possible to slow the speed of light.  These researchers got it down to 38 mph: http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/1999/02.18/light.html. The photons formed a Bose-Einstein condensate, which retains its wave nature as a single quantum mechanical entity.  An 800-atom molecule moves at less than the speed of light, as its mass precludes light speed.  Speed doesn't affect the wave nature, ceteris paribus.

Answer (score 2):

In principle there is no limit; in practice it becomes harder and harder to measure the effect as the wavelength decreases as the mass increases. Once the fringe spacing becomes small compared to the size of the molecule, it becomes almost impossible to see the fringes; similarly as the molecules get larger, the slits have to be larger to let them through; this will further blur the pattern.

But just because you can't see it doesn't mean it's not there...

Comment: So are you saying that the more atom molecules you add, this 'wave' like phenomenom will always happen? So even though I fire a nano size element of lead at two slits, big enough for it to go through, that even though I can't see it, the element is actually spliting into 2 and will interfere with its dopperganger to produce the 'wave' like pattern, when there isn't an act of measurement?!? Surely there must be a limit of how many atom molecules you can add, before this phenomenon can't occur? I wondered if anyone has ever determined the amount and asked why it losses it's 'wave' like ability.