# What is the cut off size that starts producing interference pattern in a double slit experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Firing bullets produces just two bands.

Firing elecrons or photons produces interference pattern.

What is the biggest object that produces interference pattern and the smallest one that produces two bands?

Comment: I believe buckminster fullerenes, the soccer ball shaped molecule with 60 carbon atoms, has been shown to produce the diffraction pattern.

Comment: @DRBall indeed. As well as bigger terms and molecules up to 114 atoms at least. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206831/question-about-the-double-slit-experiment-2 where something is said about the crucial point, ie detection rather than occurrence of the interference.

Comment: Your question is wrong.   **All** objects obey the equations of wave-particle duality.  Perhaps you are asking what is the largest object that has been shown in the lab to produce interference patterns?